# Get the word frequency over all rows from a column containing texts

Tags: python, pandas

Based on the (simplified) DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
texts = pd.DataFrame({"description":["This is one text","and this is another one"]})
print(texts)
               description
0         This is one text
1  and this is another on
```

I want to create Series with the word frequency of the set of words in the description column.

The expected result should look as follows:

```
           counts
this       2
is         2    
one        2
text       1
and        1
another    1
```

I tried

```
print(pd.Series('  '.join(str(texts.description)).split(' ')).value_counts())
```

but got

```
      139
e       8
t       7
i       6
n       5
o       5
s       5
d       3
a       3
h       3
p       2
:       2
c       2
r       2
\n      2
T       1
0       1
j       1
x       1
1       1
N       1
m       1
,       1
y       1
b       1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `str` in `print(pd.Series('  '.join(str(texts.description)).split(' ')).value_counts())`

This is because `str(texts.description)` returns
`'0           This is one text\n1    and this is another one\nName: description, dtype: object'` and that is not what you want.

It works like this:

```
print(pd.Series('  '.join(texts.description).split(' ')).value_counts())
```

And gives you:

```
is         2
one        2
This       1
and        1
this       1
another    1
text       1
           1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You code failed because `str(texts.description)` gives:

```
'0           This is one text\n1    and this is another one\nName: description, dtype: object'
```

that is, the string expression of the series, almost equivalent to `print(texts.description)`. And when you do `join(str(texts.description)`, the above string is converted to list of characters, and you know the rest.

Try:

```
(texts.description
      .str.lower()
      .str.split(expand=True)
      .stack().value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
this       2
one        2
is         2
another    1
and        1
text       1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = texts['description'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().split())
Counter([item for sublist in l for item in sublist])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want convert values of column to strings, use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) function:

```
print(pd.Series(' '.join(texts.description.astype(str)).split(' ')).value_counts())
```

But if all strings in column, you can also omit it and working nice:

```
print(pd.Series(' '.join(texts.description).split(' ')).value_counts())
one        2
is         2
This       1
text       1
this       1
and        1
another    1
dtype: int64
```